# Trying to get vba to "loop until" with a count

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the code to read a value from an Input box which is the desired investment amount ie. 3000. Then to read down a list (40 rows long) of the amount of btc available at a particular price, and consecutively sum up these total dollar amounts (quantity*price)  going down the list until the point where adding the next line would be greater than the desired investment amount (ie. I'm trying to see the cheapest way to acquire a bunch of btc).

I'll then write a bit to make it make up the rest of the value from the next line as it obviously won't be reached perfectly but I can't seem to get this bit to work. When I execute the code I'm getting some weird results that don't make much sense. I've put an example of a table in so you can see what I'm working with (The first price 94.25 is B3/ActiveCell)
This is probably extremely trivial but I've never done any of this stuff before. Thanks for your time and I hope I've outlined it clearly enough.

```
Sub Projected()
Dim InvestValue As Single
Dim SumBTCE As Single
Dim Sumup As Single
Dim NumBTC As Single
Dim Count As Integer

InvestValue = InputBox("Input investment amount:")
NumBTC = 0
Sumup = 0
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BTC-E Data").Cells(3, 2).Select

Do Until (Sumup + (ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 0).Value * ActiveCell.Offset(Count, 1).Value)) >= InvestValue
    For Count = 1 To 40
        Sumup = Sumup + ActiveCell.Offset(Count - 1, 0).Value * ActiveCell.Offset(Count - 1, 1).Value
        NumBTC = NumBTC + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next Count
Loop
MsgBox NumBTC
MsgBox Sumup
End Sub

price   BTC USD
94.25   0.1 9.425
94.439  0.34583324  32.66014535
94.44   2   188.88
94.443  0.011   1.038873
94.444  0.4 37.7776
94.493  0.025   2.362325
94.5    0.1 9.45
94.55   0.1 9.455
94.6    0.1 9.46
94.601  0.5 47.3005
94.648  0.0112  1.0600576
94.649  4.12801098  390.7121112
94.65   35.75926753 3384.614672
94.664  2.128011    201.4460333
94.665  3.5 331.3275
94.679  0.1395  13.2077205
94.68   0.15    14.202
94.689  2.128011    201.4992336
94.69   18.73708352 1774.214439
94.698  0.010978    1.03959464
94.699  0.093   8.807007
94.7    0.1 9.47
94.704  0.025   2.3676
94.736  0.0837  7.9294032
94.737  0.09    8.52633
94.749  2.128011    201.6269142
94.75   20.1    1904.475
94.755  0.1 9.4755
94.8    0.1 9.48
94.801  0.03758691  3.56327665
94.81   5.7236763   542.66175
94.829  0.15    14.22435
94.84   0.20095058  19.058153
94.85   0.1 9.485
94.87   0.01    0.9487
94.879  0.401   38.046479
94.88   0.01    0.9488
94.887  0.40930425  38.83765236
94.89   0.01    0.9489
94.9    0.30106377  28.57095176
```

Comment: Let me get a clarification. Your investment amount is 3000. Now you have to loop through the column price and add it up until you get 3000 or a value just below 3000? Is it like (94.25 * 0.1) + (94.439 * 0.345) ... <= 3000 ?

Comment: I'm not sure it would work, but it seems you could solve this with goal seek.

Comment: @Ian sorry for the delay, essentially I mean lesser than or equal. The action for stopping needs to be where including the next row of btc in its entirety would result in a value greater than the desired input.

Comment: @DougGlancy Hey thanks, I didn't know about that function. I'll have a go to see if I can manipulate it into doing what I want. Even if it dosen't work it'll give me something to learn about.

Comment: Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

A2 contains your goal, e.g., $3000.
C2:E41 contains your data
F2 formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C$2:C2*D$2:D2))
```

G2 formula:

```
=SUM(F$2:F2)>=$A$2
```

H2 formula:

```
=IF(G2,MAX(0,$A$2-SUM(F$1:F1)),D2)
```

Then copy the formulas down.

You could combine these formulas, but it's easier to follow this way.

[image]

Comment: Blimey, that's clever stuff. Thanks for your help! I'm trying this as a bit of a learning exercise so I'll have a go with what you've done here and see if I can actually write it in the vba module myself and incorporate it into my wider plan.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
Sub Projected()
Dim InvestValue, SumBTCE, Sumup, NumBTC As Single
Dim Count, LastRow, BTC, Price As Integer

InvestValue = InputBox("Input investment amount:")
NumBTC = 0
Sumup = 0

With Worksheets("BTC-E Data")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'finding the last row in column 2
End With

For Count = 3 To LastRow
    Price = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BTC-E Data").Range("B" & Count).Value
    BTC = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BTC-E Data").Range("C" & Count).Value
    Sumup = Sumup + (Price * BTC)
    NumBTC = NumBTC + BTC
    If Sumup >= InvestValue Then Exit For
Next

MsgBox NumBTC
MsgBox Sumup
End Sub
```

Output of the above code

NumBTC = 100.2461

Sumup = 9520.399976